# How to download glove-wiki-gigaword-100 or other word vector package using gensim.downloader behind a proxy?

Tags: api, vector, download, gensim, cpu-word

Usually, I can use the following code to download the word vector package in jupyter lab:

```
import gensim.downloader as api
word_vectors = api.load("glove-wiki-gigaword-50")
```

But now, i am using a windows server, which has a firewall. So this way does not work anymore. I also tried the way on https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim-data:

```
python -m gensim.downloader --download glove-twitter-25
```

But I do not know how to set up the proxy in this line. If my proxy is http://my-proxy.com:80. Then how can I download the word vector behind a firewall?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not use the `gensim.downloader` facility at all, given the extra complexity/hidden-steps it introduces (which include [what I consider an unnecessary security risk](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2283) of downloading & running extra 'shim' Python code that's not in the normal Gensim release).

Instead, find the plain dataset you want, download it to somewhere you can, then use whatever other method you have for transferring files to your firewalled Windows Server.

Specifically, the 50d GLoVe vectors appear to be included as part of the `glove.6B.zip` download available on the canonical GLoVe home page:

https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/

Comment: thanks for your idea. if I manually download one, I do not know how to use it. For example, when i use api.load: model = api.load("glove-twitter-25"), I can use this way to find the vectors: model.most_similar("cat"). But I do not know how to do such things when downloading by myself. Could you please give me an example?

Comment: See the docs here for examples of what you can do once you have a `GLoVe`-format file - including converting it to a slightly-more standard format & loading it for lookup/similar operations: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim_3.8.3/scripts/glove2word2vec.html

Comment: I have issue loading the model. When I download the file **glove.840B.300d.zip**. What to do now? I want to convert each of my text to a vector for text classification.

Comment: ~mah65, it sounds like you have some other question, which should be asked separately with a clear description of what your goal is, what you've tried, and how what you've tried hasn't worked as expected.